# Handle multiple dependency project have persistance.xml with common pesistance manager

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have multiple dependency as a normally project have, and each have their own persistence.xml, the datasource is provided to the dependent project with the following configuration...

```
<bean id="PUM" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">       <property name="persistenceXmlLocations"><!-- default -->           <list>
                <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>          </list>         </property>         <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="DS" />  </bean> <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" init-method="method1"/>
```

My Question is, if I am using hibernate, can I over ride the dialect over the mentioned in persistance.xml in dependency projects...in case using hibernate...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create EntityManager manually using [EntityManagerFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html#createEntityManager-java.util.Map-).  In this way, you may pass additional properties, that would add to or overwrite properties set in persistence.xml file. As hibernate dialect is a plain property, you may overwrite it in following way:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = // retrieve from spring configuration
Map<String,String> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", 
         "Your desired dialect as would be written in persistence.xml");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(jpaProperties);
```